# Hibernate internationalized User titles

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the usual Customer table but I would like to be able to let the customer choose a title (like Mr., Mrs., Dr. etc).

However the web site is multilingual. No matter what title he chooses I would like to address him with it's equivalent title of the language he or she is viewing the web site.

So I imagine something like:

```
Customer                        CustomerTitles                               
--------                        --------------
titleId     -------|            id
firstName          |--------    titleId
lastName                        locale
                                titleDescription
```

Any thoughts on how can I implement the classes using hibernate annotations?

Comment: What's your precise question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one CustomerTitle can belong to many Customers, so it can be mapped with a ManyToOne relationship (with the Customer at the owning side) in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
public class Customer
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="titleId")
    private CustomerTitle title;

    ....
}


@Entity
@Table(name="CustomerTitles")
public class CustomerTitle
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;

    private String title;        

    private String locale;

    private String titleDescription;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need a table to map equivalent titles. That is, a map between the internationalized title and the arch-title. Seed this with mappings.

I would then have a `@JoinColumn` field for the arch-title, and a `@Transient` field for the internationalized title. Then specify a `@PrePersist` handler to use the transient field to look up and set the arch-title. From that point you can use the arch-title.

Answer (score 0):

Finanally the way I did and got acceptable results was:

```
Customer               Title               TitleLocalization
--------               ------              -----------------
id              |---1  id      1---|       id
titleId     N---|                  |---N   titleId
firstName                                  locale
lastName                                   title (localized)
```

The Customer class:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Title title;
}
```

The Title class:

```
@Entity
public class Title implements Serializable {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @MapKey(name = "locale")
  private Map<Locale, TitleLocalization> localized;
}
```

And the TitleLocalization class:

```
@Entity
public class TitleLocalization implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ManyToOne 
  private Title title;

  private Locale locale;

  private String traslation;
```

so I can "easily" get the translated customer title from the view: eg.

```
#{login.currCustomer.title.localized.get(localeManager.currLocale).title}
```